# Finding if 2 polygons intersect using clipper library

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, geometry, clipping

After realising my code was pretty inefficient at checking for polygon overlaps, I've turned to a mentioned library [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) but finding it difficult to know hot to use it for this operation.

I am using unity Vector2[] for my shape descriptions:

```
//Square
Vector2[] square = new Vector2[] {
    new Vector2(0,0),
    new Vector2(1,0),
    new Vector2(1,1), 
    new Vector2(0,1)
};
```

[image]

I want to be able to do the above boolean comparison of 2 shapes. If anyone knows Clipper well, what methods can I use to do this check?

I've recently tried the following but the result is always true even when the test shapes are completely separate from each other:

```
public bool CheckForOverLaps(Vector2[] shape1, Vector2[] shape2) {

    List<IntPoint> shape1IntPoints = Vector2ArrayToListIntPoint (shape1);
    List<IntPoint> shape2IntPoints = Vector2ArrayToListIntPoint (shape2);

    List<List<IntPoint>> solution = new List<List<IntPoint>> ();

    c.AddPath (shape1IntPoints, PolyType.ptSubject, true);
    c.AddPath (shape2IntPoints, PolyType.ptClip, true);
    c.Execute (ClipType.ctIntersection, solution, PolyFillType.pftNonZero, PolyFillType.pftNonZero);
    return solution.Count != 0;

}

private List<IntPoint> Vector2ArrayToListIntPoint (Vector2[] shape) {

    List<IntPoint> list = new List<IntPoint> ();

    foreach (Vector2 v in shape) {

        list.Add (new IntPoint (v.x, v.y));

    }

    return list;

}
```

And the tests:

```
    //Square
    Vector2[] square = new Vector2[] {
        new Vector2(0,0),
        new Vector2(2,0),
        new Vector2(2,2), 
        new Vector2(0,2)
    };

    //Square
    Vector2[] square2 = new Vector2[] {
        new Vector2 (1, 1),
        new Vector2 (3, 1),
        new Vector2 (3, 3), 
        new Vector2 (1, 3)
    };

    //Square
    Vector2[] square3 = new Vector2[] {
        new Vector2 (2, 0),
        new Vector2 (4, 0),
        new Vector2 (4, 2), 
        new Vector2 (2, 2)
    };

    //Square
    Vector2[] square4 = new Vector2[] {
        new Vector2 (4, 0),
        new Vector2 (6, 0),
        new Vector2 (6, 2), 
        new Vector2 (4, 2)
    };


    Assert.IsTrue(tc.CheckForOverLaps(square,square2));
    Assert.IsFalse(tc.CheckForOverLaps(square,square3));
    Assert.IsFalse(tc.CheckForOverLaps(square,square4));
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this in the end.. I had to Clear() out clipper for the next tests to work. Converted everything to IntPoint before hand to improve efficiency.

```
public bool CheckForOverLaps(List<IntPoint> shape1, List<IntPoint> shape2) {

    clipper.Clear();
    solution.Clear ();

    clipper.AddPath (shape1, PolyType.ptSubject, true);
    clipper.AddPath (shape2, PolyType.ptClip, true);
    clipper.Execute (ClipType.ctIntersection, solution, PolyFillType.pftNonZero, PolyFillType.pftNonZero);

    return solution.Count != 0;
}
```